# Can't create tag synonym "l2e" because it's considered as a version specific tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I wanted to create a synonym for the [linq-to-entities](/questions/tagged/linq-to-entities) tag. The synonym [l2e](/questions/tagged/l2e) already exists as a tag. But I can't because apparently the "2" in the tag name lets the system assume that this tag is version specific:

[image: lt2 tag]

I also created a little mess when I added the [lte](/questions/tagged/lte) tag accidentally (has nothing to do with LINQ). I'm sorry. I can't vote my own proposal down nor delete the proposal.

Could a moderator add the tag synonym [l2e](/questions/tagged/l2e) and delete or vote down the wrong synonym [lte](/questions/tagged/lte)? Thanks!